# Intel x86 Assembly - Can't figure out looping

Tags: assembly, x86, intel

I'm trying to loop 5 times and print "Hello World\n" for each loop.
Regardless of whether I use jmp(jge, jle) and sub from ecx or use loopne, the loop either continues forever, or else not at all.
I don't understand why the loop doesn't break when the counter reaches zero.

```
.intel_syntax noprefix
.globl  main
.type   main, @function
main:
    endbr64
    push    rbp
    mov ecx, 5      # set counter to 5
    call looper
    pop rbp
    ret


.globl looper
.type   looper, @function
looper:

    lea rdi, str[rip]       #load the string
    call puts       #print the string each loop

    mov eax, ecx
    cmp eax, 0
    loopne looper  # dec counter and loop if counter not zero

    ret

str:
    .string "Hello World\n"
```

Comment: In case the duplicates don't make it clear, the problem is that `puts` overwrites `ecx`.

Comment: perfect, thank you